# set EditText line itself length

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to have something like this : 
the ___ is the EditText, the () is the button, the --- is the rest of the screen
___________()
how can i make the line to always take the place until the button?
when i rotate the screen the edittext line should get until the button as well.
but this is what i get: 
_______()-----
This is what i have right now and dont know what to change:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width=""
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/word" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should explain what you need in more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/word"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button should have weight=0, so the EditText always gets all the unused screen space. É voila.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:maxLength="15"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width=""
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/word" />

<Button
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```